# Hibernate L2 cache issues with EntityGraph and LEFT JOIN FETCH queries

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-cache

I'm using hibernate 5.3.14 with hazelcast 3.11.5 as L2 cache provider and spring boot 2.1.11.

I have 3 entities defined with relations:

- one order has many order items
- one order has many custom fields
  L2 cache is enabled for entities, associations and queries.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage =CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Order extends AbstractBaseEntity implements Orderable {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private List<OrderItem> orderItems;

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractBaseEntity

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_rid")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
    private List<CustomField> customFields = new ArrayList<>();

@Entity
@Table(name = "custom_fields")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class CustomField implements Serializable {

@Entity
@Table(name = "order_items")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class OrderItem extends AbstractBaseEntity implements Orderable {
```

I have one repository:

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, String> {

    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = "customFields")
    Optional<Order> findById(String rid);

    @QueryHints(value = {@QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "true")})
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = "customFields")
    @Query("select o from Order left join fetch o.orderItems where o.status = 'ACTIVE' ")
    List<Order> findAllActiveWithOrderItems();
```

There are 3 problems:

1. repo method `findById` doesn't load from the cache the main entity, order, with the relation, customFields, indicated by entity graph loaded
2. cached query results for repo method `findAllActiveWithOrderItems` does not seem to have the relations,  orderItems, loaded by the FETCH JOIN
3. cached query results
   for repo    method `findAllActiveWithOrderItems` does not seem to have the relations loaded by the the EntityGraph, customFields

Are there any known hibernate tickets or workarounds to fix those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a known issue and I think Hibernate 6.0 will fix it, but I don't remember if there ever was a ticket for this.

Comment: Thanks. I found the hibernate ticket for the 1th and 3rd problem https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10179. But the second problem about honoring the LEFT JOIN FETCH on cached queries I still have no clue.

Comment: Also for caching the results of a FETCH JOIN query there is a hibernate bug opened: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2003